# BroadFileSystemAccess is not working even it added in package.appmanfiest

Tags: uwp

1.Even i followed the link [broadFileSystemAccess for UWP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802498/broadfilesystemaccess-for-uwp-not-working) it cannot able to access in capability?.
2.when i tried to add this code in capability `<respectability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />` .

Please mention if any possibility?.

And my windows version build 18362.

Comment: Did you enable it in the apps settings in the Windows Settings app? Even if you enable in manifest, the user needs to manually open the settings app and allow permission

Comment: @johnny,it is important that i need to be an member of developer center or Partner to access an broadFileSystemAccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Johnny Westlake` said, after add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, you also need to manually enable broad file system in File System setting page. For getting the setting page, you could search file system keywords in setting app home page.

[image]

If you want to quickly access this page, you could use the following method. For more info please refer [**Launch the Windows Settings app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-broadfilesystemaccess"));
```

Comment: ,yes i understand that need to give access in File System for particular app.But i need to know are you in community of developer center,Because If your app declares any **restricted capabilities**, you must provide info during the app **submission process** in order to be approved to publish the app to the Microsoft Store

Comment: ,Thank for your information.And now i get what an issue ,So i am not an member of **Developer Center** .So that i cannot able to add in Package.appmanfiest for restricted capability.

Comment: Do you have developer account for Microsoft store ?

Comment: ,no I do not have an account,and if any possibility to access without develop center account.Please be mention

Comment: If you don't  have account, I'm afraid you could not publish the app the Microsoft store . For this scenario you could try to install your app with sideload way.

Comment: by using sideload app,it asking an developer license

Comment: Do you mean that need certificate for sideload way?

Comment: ok, thank you, so developer license is must for using restricted capability.

Comment: developer license is not necessary, if you do not want to publish to shore, you could  use sideload way to install app, and please make sure install the package certificate first.

Comment: ,then why when i try to add  **<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">**

Comment: 2.then i tried to implement **<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings"/>
</Capabilities>** it shows error in this command

Comment: I tried this capability, and it works in my side, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities).

Comment: ,yes now i understand that restricted capability its work in sideload,but when trying to  publish it may has no permission.So now i understand thank you.

Comment: Do you have any updates for this case? please feel free post in the case update.

Comment: not working in sideload app,please mention an steps to follow

Comment: Have you create appx package successfully?

Comment: have you packaged the app like `FileAccessTest_1.0.9.0_x64.appx` for sideload?

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) for the detail steps.

Comment: no i don,t have an ** FileAccessTest_1.0.9.0_x64.appx**

Comment: Please check above document to create the appx file.